# How does one request / handle personal or financial information?

Tags: licensing, security, coding-standards, applications

I would like to create a budget app for Android. Obviously, to be competitive, I would need to allow users to get data from their bank. For [huge] security reasons, this stuff is not just freely given to any would be developer, but I know it can be done. There are budget apps that connected to users banks.

My question is, what do I need to do to poll users bank data? Do I need to contact every bank that I wish my app to deal with? Do I need to write the app and present it the the bank(s)? Or am I just too ignorant to take on a challenge of this magnitude?

I ask because I obviously don't know the standards that are needed here and would like to learn about them, even if it ends up that I cannot write the bank interface section of my app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to check out [OFX](http://www.ofx.net/).  This is how programs all get their data.  Banks have gone to (a version) of it and pretty much moved away from the QIF format formerly used by Quicken.

Unforturately, Banks mostly use [QFX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QFX_%28file_format%29), the intuit extension/variant of OFX.  Banks have to pay Intuit to use it so don't expect to get free and easy access to it unless (big banks never miss an opportunity to charge you)

Comment: Many thanks for giving me some standards. This will really help me along.